# how can I restart winform?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two windows form in C# . f1 calls f2.I use message box.if the user press 'ok' , the program most restart f2 again and  if press 'cancel',program close f2.
for pressing 'ok' :
I couldn't use 'Application.restart()',because all program restarted and I just want to restart f2. when I use  " f2 f=new(); f.show();this.close();" all program closed.

please learn to me how can I solve this problem? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do `this.Close();` after showing `f`. Instead, just hide your form.

```
f2 f = new f2();
f.Show();
this.Hide();
```

f1 will they stay running and you can reuse it.

Comment: excuse me .now I test f2 f=new(); f.show();this.close(); again and it worked .I don't know why before now it doesn't worked. I 'm so sorry.

Comment: when I used "this. hide()",f2 didn't close until application exited.